# Selenium fails to kill browser when test fails

Tags: java, firefox, browser, junit, selenium

How do I set up Selenium to kill the test browser page on occasions where the test fails?

Currently, when running Selenium test cases and a test fails, the browser page stays open and that causes problems when a large number of tests is failing. Interestingly enough, it isn't the case when the test passes.

Any suggestion??

Comment: when you start the test, does it open a new browser, or does it use one that's already open?  If the latter, you may not have the browser configured correctly.  I think you have to configure the browser to open new pages in a new window.  This might affect the close, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you mean when i start the test or when each test case runs? Each test case currently opens a new browser and closes at the end of the test. Currently, as mentioned above, it only closes when tests pass but stays open when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not quite that simple, in my experience anyway (I'm new to selenium and JUnit). It depends how the failure occurs and what you do with it. JUnit should automatically call tearDown() when a test fails, and selenium.stop() should be in this. However sometimes tearDown() isn't called, for instance when the error occurs in setUp(), or if you're doing something sill when a failure occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You should call selenium.stop() of course :) It sounds like you need a try/finally block